# How to sort a hashed table in C

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, hashtable

So I have a hash table of `struct`s (called `Object`) that uses linked lists to handle collision. The struct has:

1. an `int` field named `val`
2. a `char[]` field named `type`
3. a pointer to  another `struct` named `*nextPtr`

My program needs to get the number of `Object`s the user is going to input, allocate an array of lists of `Object`s, and get that number of input members.

The index is calculated using the following hash function: each character making up the `type` string is summed after being cast to `unsigned int`, then the function returns that sum modulo 2 times the number of members in the array.

When a new `Object` is input (the program will prompt for its `type` first, then its `val`), its hashed position is calculated and one of three things can happen:

1. if the chained list in that position doesn't contain an `Object` that has the same `type` as the one input, that `Object` is inserted at the head of the list
2. if the chained list in that position contains an `Object` with the same `type` atribute as the one input, and the input `val` is greater than that of the `Object` in that position, then the `val` field of that `Object` is updated with the new value-
3. otherwise, no action is performed.

After filling the map, it needs to be sorted decreasingly by `val` and, when two `Object`s with the same `val` field are encountered, they need to be sorted lexicographically.

Lastly, the first 15 elements of the table need to be printed or, if there are less than 15 elements, all the array is printed.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to sort a hash map. This is literally the first time I deal with them. I've done some research but can't quite find an answer. I can't just sort the array because each member is a list itself.

Below you can find the code I've written so far and an example of input/expected output. The strings are Italian words, hope it's not a problem as the meaning doesn't matter.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct obj {
    char type[20];
    int val;
    struct obj *nextPtr;
} Object;


int hash(char a[], int mod) {
    mod *= 2;

    int sum = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
        sum += (unsigned int) a[i];
    }

    return sum % mod;
}

Object *newNode(char *type, int val) {
    Object *newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Object));
    if(newPtr == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    strcpy(newPtr->type, type);
    newPtr->val = val;
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

    return newPtr;
}

void hashedInsert(Object **lPtr, char *type, int val) {
    if(*lPtr == NULL) {
        *lPtr = newNode(type, val); // list is empty, append new element
        return;
    }
    if(strcmp((*lPtr)->type, type)) { // list doesn't contain the input element, insert it at top
        Object *newPtr = newNode(type, val);
        newPtr->nextPtr = *lPtr;
        *lPtr = newPtr;
        return;
    }

    if(val > (*lPtr)->val) // update val if input val is greater than the existing one
        (*lPtr)->val = val;
}

int main() {
    int numObjects;

    scanf("%d", &numObjects); // get number of objects

    Object **dictionary = malloc(sizeof(Object*) * 2 * numObjects); // allocate memory for dictionary
    if(dictionary == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < (2*numObjects); i++) {
        dictionary[i] = malloc(sizeof(Object)); // allocate single rows
        if(dictionary[i] == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;

        dictionary[i] = NULL; // all lists are initialized as empty
    }

    char thisType[20];
    int thisVal, thisHashed;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        scanf("%s", thisType); // get object type field
        scanf("%d", &thisVal); // get object val field

        thisHashed = hash(thisType, numObjects); // calculate position of insertion using hash function

        hashedInsert(&(dictionary[thisHashed]), thisType, thisVal); // insert according to defined insertion rules
    }

    // HOW DO I SORT THE MAP???

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if(dictionary[i] == NULL) break;
        else printf("%s\n", dictionary[i]->type);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Example input/output:

```
input: (first line is the number of objects)
21
Frigorifero
30
Frigorifero
60
Telefono
50
Asciugamano
10
Libro
5
Libro
100
Tovaglia
70
Computer
120
Scarpe
160
Ventilatore
1
Bilancia
1
Cestino
1
Tazza
1
Cuscino
1
Trolley
1
Appendiabiti
1
Termometro
1
Penna
1
Matita
1
Orologio
1
Abat-jour
1


--
output:

Scarpe
Computer
Libro
Tovaglia
Frigorifero
Telefono
Asciugamano
Abat-jour
Appendiabiti
Bilancia
Cestino
Cuscino
Matita
Orologio
Penna
```

To view the structure of the hashmap, without sorting, you can use this code

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < numObjects*2; i++) {
        if(dictionary[i] == NULL) printf("NULL\n");
        else {
         printf("(%d) %s - %d\n", hash(dictionary[i]->type, numObjects), dictionary[i]->type, dictionary[i]->val);
         Object *currPtr = dictionary[i]->nextPtr;
         while(currPtr != NULL) {
            printf("\t (%d) %s - %d\n", hash(currPtr->type, numObjects), currPtr->type, currPtr->val);
            currPtr = currPtr->nextPtr;
         }
        }
    }
```

It'll print the hash-computed position of the `Object`, then its `type` and `val`, and will also print all the `Object`s in the same hash-computed position (so those following the first one that are in a list).

Thank you to anyone who will respond!

Comment: In the insert function, I cannot find a place where you are walking the linked list. Only a single strcmp(). Also: the hash function is not used.

Comment: I don't need to walk anything, if an insertion happens, it's at the head of the list. Did you read my post? The hash function is used here: ```hashedInsert(&(dictionary[thisHashed]), thisType, thisVal);``` after it's been called here: ```thisHashed = hash(thisType, numObjects);```

Comment: Did you consider using [qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) ? Perhaps sorting an array of pointers ..?

Comment: Then: what is the need for the hash function?

Comment: @Basile I thought of doing it this way. But then will I not just sort the first pointers of each list?

Comment: Aside: Curious the cast in `sum += (unsigned int) a[i];` lacks benefit.  Did you mean `sum += (unsigned char) a[i];`?

Comment: `dictionary[i] = NULL;` Just after `malloc` you erase the pointer, memory leak. Sort and hashmap is very strange

Comment: @wildplasser what do you mean?

Comment: @chux no I meant int. But like you said, probably it wasn't necessary. Just realized it.

Comment: @Orel I realize it's a weird combo. However this is the problem that was given a couple of years ago for an exam I'll take in a few months. So I need to be prepared for this sort of things too.

Comment: `hash(..., numObjects)` looks amiss.  It returns a value in the `[0...2*numObjects)` range, possible even `(-2*numObjects ... 2*numObjects)` with a super long string.  Should not its results be limited to   `[0...numObjects)`?   ......Ah I see a `2*numObjects` allocations lurking in other code. Oh well.

Comment: @chux no, the assignment requires us to create a table that is twice as long as the number of objects. Also, we are allowed to assume there will not be any overflow.

Comment: But why are you doing the hashing in main()? BTW Hint: don't use signed types for hashing. The modulo operator could result in negative indexes.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like I managed to find a way to make this work.  I found a working solution by flattening the data to an array, then sorting that array. I basically copy all the elements to an array, so I get the chained lists out of the way, then call `qsort` on that array.

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct obj {
    char type[100];
    int val;
    struct obj *nextPtr;
} Object;

int cmpfun(const void* a, const void* b) { // used by qsort
    Object** x = (Object **) a;
    Object** y = (Object **) b;

    if ((*x)->val > (*y)->val)
        return -1;
    if ((*x)->val < (*y)->val)
        return 1;

    if (strcmp((*x)->type, (*y)->type) > 0) // vals were equal, compare types
        return 1;
    return -1;
}

int hash(char a[], int mod) {
    mod *= 2;

    int sum = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
        sum += (unsigned int) a[i];
    }

    return sum % mod;
}

Object *newNode(char *type, int val) {
    Object *newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Object));
    if(newPtr == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    strcpy(newPtr->type, type);
    newPtr->val = val;
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

    return newPtr;
}

void hashedInsert(Object **lPtr, char *type, int val, int *objCount) {
    if(*lPtr == NULL) {
        *lPtr = newNode(type, val); // list is empty, append new element
        *objCount = *objCount + 1;
        return;
    }
    if(strcmp((*lPtr)->type, type)) { // list doesn't contain the input element, insert it at top
        Object *newPtr = newNode(type, val);
        newPtr->nextPtr = *lPtr;
        *lPtr = newPtr;
        *objCount = *objCount + 1;
        return;
    }

    if(val > (*lPtr)->val) // update val if input val is greater than the existing one
        (*lPtr)->val = val;
}

void flatten(Object **input, int n, Object **output) { // scans through the hashtable and copies the data to an array
    size_t j = 0;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(input[i] != NULL) {
            output[j++] = input[i];

            Object *nextChild = input[i]->nextPtr;
            while(nextChild != NULL) { // copy all the nodes of the list in the i-th position of the original array
                output[j++] = nextChild;
                nextChild = nextChild->nextPtr;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int numObjects;
    int distinctObjs = 0;

    scanf("%d", &numObjects); // get number of objects

    Object **dictionary = malloc(sizeof(Object*) * 2 * numObjects); // allocate memory for dictionary
    if(dictionary == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < (2*numObjects); i++) {
        dictionary[i] = malloc(sizeof(Object)); // allocate single rows
        if(dictionary[i] == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;      
    }

    char thisType[100];
    int thisVal, thisHashed;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        scanf("%s", thisType); // get object type field
        scanf("%d", &thisVal); // get object val field

        thisHashed = hash(thisType, numObjects); // calculate position of insertion using hash function

        hashedInsert(&(dictionary[thisHashed]), thisType, thisVal, &distinctObjs); // insert according to defined insertion rules
    }

    Object **flattenedDictionary = malloc(sizeof(Object *) * distinctObjs);
    if(flattenedDictionary == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < distinctObjs; i++) {
        flattenedDictionary[i] = malloc(sizeof(Object)); // allocate single rows
        if(flattenedDictionary[i] == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    flatten(dictionary, numObjects*2, flattenedDictionary);

    qsort(flattenedDictionary, distinctObjs, sizeof(Object*), cmpfun);

    if(distinctObjs > 15) distinctObjs = 15; // If there are less than 15 distinct objects, printing the first 15 means printing the whole array

    for(size_t i = 0; i < distinctObjs; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", flattenedDictionary[i]->type);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```